# Can't run typeorm cli commands with expo-sqlite driver SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo, typeorm

I have a React Native project with TypeORM and expo-sqlite driver. I need to use TypeORM CLI in order to revert specific migration files.

**data-source.ts**

```
...
import "reflect-metadata";
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import * as sqlite from 'expo-sqlite';
...
const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    ...
    driver: sqlite,
    type: 'expo',
    ...
});

AppDataSource.initialize().then(() => {
    console.log("Data Source has been initialized!");
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error during Data Source initialization", err.message);
});

export default AppDataSource;
```

As docs says, in order to run cli commands, we need to transpile `.ts` files by running `typeorm-ts-node-esm` in my case since I'm using ES modules. After setting up cli and running it in the same way as docs suggests, I get an error saying:

```
Error during migration revert:
Error: Unable to open file: "[absolute path to project]/src/data-source.ts". Unexpected token 'export'
```

Tried to transpile a datasource file with **ts-node** and got a message similar to which **typeorm-ts-node-esm** was giving, which points to expo-sqlite package:

```
(node:12220) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/[absolute path to project]/node_modules/expo-sqlite/build/index.js:1
export * from './SQLite';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

And the package has following lines in **index.js** file specified in error message:

```
export * from './SQLite';
export * from './SQLite.types';
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

The problem is that even though it seems like someone has faced this issue too, but as for me none of provided solution works. I already tried to set up `"type": "module"` in my **package.json** file, tried to configure **tsconfig.json** which looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2020", "DOM", "ESNext"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "jsx": "react-native",
  "noEmit": true,
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  }
}
```

Which has barely to no effect at all. I managed to revert migrations programatically through `AppDataSource.undoLastMigration()` but this doesn't revert specific migration and it's seems to me like a workaround and not a complete solution.

Just in case, this is my **package.json** containing some of dependencies:

```
"type": "module",
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "expo-sqlite": "11.5.0",
    "metro-minify-terser": "^0.77.0",
    "pg": "^8.4.0",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.6",
    "typeorm": "0.3.11",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.10",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "4.6.3"
},
```

Anyone knows how can I solve this problem?